# install android studio - ubuntu 16 - package 5.2.1

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

While installing android studio, I have a fail error saying that the package droid studio 5.2.1 failed to install. I have attached the journal errors to see the logs...[image]

Comment: That log doesn't seem to be related with "Android Studio", it is an ACPI error

Answer (score 0):

try this command : 
sudo apt-get install android-studio

Comment: I don't think this would change much to the problem.